# Should stacks be made from arrays or linked list java?

Tags: java, stack

I have to write a stack for class and while I understand the concept of how a stack works, I wasn't told  if they are made using an array or a linked list or something else? How are most stacks created?

Comment: Linked list seems more appropriate.  It has good growth behaviour and you don't need to access elements by index with a stack.

Comment: The best implementation depends on the requirements of the application.

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayDeque` is a solid class implementation of the stack concept. This class has implemented stack in the most efficient way. Please look at the class implementation for the details of various methods.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.java.html

More specifically, look at `public E pollFirst(){...}` and `public void addFirst(E e)`

Comment: Can you point us to a source that shows that a deque is more efficient than a simple linked list? I don't dispute that it's faster that a java.util.Stack, since that's also array-based, but can you back up the claim that it's faster than a LinkedList?

Comment: The answer seems to be completely unrelated to the question. The OP asked which implementation option *he* should take, not what JRE class to use.

Comment: @Durandal I wouldn't use "Completely unrelated" as I have directed the user to see what the state-of-the-art implementation looks like.

Comment: Well maybe completely was a little too strong, but the OP doesn't need a *state of the art* implementation (without any reasoning why *that* makes a good implementation, but *lots of unrelated* methods to confuse him btw.), he needs to write just *an implementation* as an excercise :)

Comment: Thank you .. I see your point .. I'll point out the methods he can use.

Answer (score 1):

[java.util.Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is a subclass of java.util.Vector which was a Thread-safe precursor to ArrayList. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both options, array and linked list are appropiate.

A linked list may be simpler because you needn't worry about the array size. An array based implementation on the other hand may have better runtime behavior and can be easier to debug (because its easier to view the array than a linked list in the debugger).

Chose whatever you're comfortable with.